# Spark: Naive Bayes over jdbc Dataset<Row>

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to use Spark's MLLib Naive Bayes algorithm to make some predictions. Unfortunately I can't make it 'cause apparently the algorithms works with a "libsvm" format (label label:feature) that I can't get from my Data Set. I'm Working on Java and I obtain the data from a MySQL Database... Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class SparkML {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //This two lines hide spark logs
        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

        //Here I create the spark session
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test").config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate();

        // This three lines take care of DB connection   
        Properties dbProperties = new Properties();
        dbProperties.load(new FileInputStream(new File("properties.flat")));
        String jdbcUrl = dbProperties.getProperty("jdbcUrl");

        // Retrieving training data
        String table = "spark_tests.sparkTrainData";
        Dataset<Row> train = spark.read().jdbc(jdbcUrl, table, dbProperties);

        // Retrieving test data    
        table = "spark_tests.sparkTrainData";
        Dataset<Row> test = spark.read().jdbc(jdbcUrl, table, dbProperties);

        NaiveBayes nb = new NaiveBayes();
        NaiveBayesModel model = nb.fit(train); //When executing this, I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist."    
    }
}
```

Any Idea on how I can achieve this? Or if there's another way to do it? I've already checked Spark's APIs, Spark's Tutorials and they only work with *.txt files

Answer (score 1):

> MLlib supports local vectors and matrices stored on a single machine, as well as distributed matrices backed by one or more RDDs. Local vectors and local matrices are simple data models that serve as public interfaces. The underlying linear algebra operations are provided by Breeze. A training example used in supervised learning is called a “labeled point” in MLlib.

[From Spark MLlib Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html)

You have to transform your data to a "labeled point", if you provide a example of your train data maybe i can help you with the code...